# Mailing List Module not working

Tags: forms, 2.7.0, mailinglist, mailing

I'm using the following code in my template for a Mailing List form, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
{exp:mailinglist:form
    list="default"
}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" value="{email}">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
{/exp:mailinglist:form}
```

The form seems to post though no email appears in my default mailing list. Any thoughts on what could be the issue? I'm on 2.7 and am using .htaccess to remove the index.php.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (posted in the thread referenced above) - confirm that I can also send mails from Communicate. I am guessing it must be server related as I can send on exactly the same db hen it's local.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in ExpressionEngine 2.7. I've filed a bug report. Will be fixed in the next version.

There's some info on how to fix it on the ExpressionEngine bug tracker
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19733 and on the forum http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237991/#1059052

Comment: I used the information provided in the forum and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you CAN send an email.
Send a test email in the communicate window. Otherwise your code looks ok.
[communicate](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/communicate.html)

Also, read this [Emails sent via ExpressionEngine are never reaching their destination](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/troubleshooting/email/emails_not_reaching_destination.html)

Ok, can you receive the email from mailing list? I assume you are inputting a valid email. Docs say this

> The Mailing List is an opt in type, meaning that when someone adds their email address to the list, they are sent a confirmation email containing a link with an access code. Unless they click the link, their email address will not be added to the list. The opt-in link will expire in 48 hours. Conversely, when someone in your mailing list receives an email, there will be an “unsubscribe” link permitting them to remove themselves from the list`.

Just tested your link. Yep, no email received.
[some one else having same issue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/mailing-list-error-on-live-but-not-local-install)

One last idea, the source shows action id 19.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="19">
```

Make sure this action id is listed in db table exp_actions.

Finally, and im guessing here, move this mailing list tag off the home screen to another template and retest. Forms submit to home screen. I wonder if this is causing an issue here?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I was able to send a test email through successfully, but I'm still unable to use the Mailing List form module to add an email address to my default mailing list on the frontend. You can [try it out here](http://downtownlving.com/) by clicking on "Sign Up for Updates". After hitting submit it will take you back to the frontpage, but no email address is added to the backend.

Comment: I verified that the action id is listed in that db table. Also tested the [form on another template](http://downtownlving.com/test), but no email is being added to the backend. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry Roger. Youve got me stumped. Hopefully someone else can offer a suggestion. You appear to have done it as per docs. I currently have another issue relating to email where hotmail activations arent be received. Thats got me stumped too. Maybe our issues are related. Maybe not.

Comment: If you try to add the same email address to your list from the control panel, does it work?

Comment: Yep, just tried adding through CP and it showed up just fine.